# Optimising cross platform build system

Tags: c, optimization, build, cross-platform

I'm looking for a cross platform build system for C which helps to find good compiler flags on a specific machine. It would need some notions of testing for correctness, benchmarking for performance and multiple versioning of the target, and perhaps even recognising the machine it is running on. For example, in a typical build I'd want to compare 64 bit versus 32 bit executables, with and without openmp, fast-math, with different optimisation levels, and builds by entirely different compilers. The atlas-blas libraries are an impressive example here but are a bit of a pain on windows due the shell scripting. Is this something that can be hacked onto systems like Scons or Waf? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the one I'm thinking about writing when I'm done procrastinating, Boost Jam (bjam) would probably match your description closest.

Answer (score 0):

There is also CMake, but I think it would require a scripting layer to automate multi-target building and testing.